# God mode in Doom 3 on Xbox Series X/S

Tags: cheats, xbox-series-x-series-s, doom-3

Are cheat codes disabled in Doom 3 on the Xbox Series X/S? For God mode, I keep seeing Left trigger + X, Y, B, A or Left tigger + A, A, A, A, but neither seem to work for me.